# How to set up Mosquitto bridging configuration?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I wanted to set up a test configuration of Mosquitto. For one configuration file, I wrote only this:

```
listener 1883
```

I started a server with this config file, and it started successfully.

The second config file has the following:

```
listener 1884
connection test
address 127.0.0.1:1883
```

When I try to start the server with this, I get the following error message:

```
Error: Invalid bridge configuration.
Error: Unable to open configuration file.
```

It does not matter whether I try it with or without the other server running, or if I try an external address or a local one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide a `topic` section to your bridge to tell the broker which topics to bridge.

e.g.

```
listener 1884
connection test
address 127.0.0.1:1883
topic foo/# in
```

This will bridge into the second broker all topics starting `foo/` from the first broker.

Looks at the mosquitto.conf [man](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) page for more details about the `topic` keyword